# Fast count of records in entity

Tags: swift, core-data

I'd like to count all records of each entity in my model, to get a global overview of what it contains.

I used `context.count(for: request)` to get the global count, but it takes ~10s to execute in an entity with ~400 000 records.

Is there any faster way to query the number of records ?
I imagine `context.count()` is fairly optimized, but maybe it still fetches some stuff to the cache, which I don't need ?

Code:

```swift
var counts : [String: Int] = [:]
for entity in self.container.managedObjectModel.entities {
    let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: entity.name!)
    do {
        let count = try mainContext.count(for: request)
        counts[entity.name!] = count
    } catch {
        Logger.error("Couldn't count entity \(entity.name)")
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah great idea to look at the SQL query. Well that settles it then :) want to add the answer so I can accept it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking the Core Data debug logs it is clear that `count(for:)` is translated to the SQL statement `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ...` and there is no other way that is faster than that for counting the number of rows (objects) in a table.

And since the only thing returned is an `Int` value nothing gets cached because of using `count(for:)`